# ASP.NET eval() always return true

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

Im very new to eval() fun ction concept ,so dont judge me on syntax.

I have my Eval function :

```
<%# Eval("BooleanVariable").ToString() == "true" ? GetAnswerWhenVariableIsTrue(Eval("Uid").ToString()) : GetAbnswerWhenVariableIsFalse(Eval("Uid").ToString())%>
```

So what i want is, when Boolean variable is true to call GetAnswerWhenVariableIsTrue and when false GetAbnswerWhenVariableIsFalse

How can i achieve it?

im using it to load input controls into repeater dynamicly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("BooleanVariable")) == true ? GetAnswerWhenVariableIsTrue(Eval("Uid").ToString()) : GetAbnswerWhenVariableIsFalse(Eval("Uid").ToString())%>
```